# How to add Custom Ribbon in SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, ribbon

I want to add one custom ribbon in all my lists in sharepoint.The ribbon for to upload and download the documents.

If i click the custom ribbon popup should open and i should upload the folder or Bulk Document it will added to list as a item.
and i want to Download bulk document from sharepoint list.

How can i achieve this.See the screenshot below.
The default Document library having the same functionality to upload documents but i want to upload folders also.

[SharePoint Default Ribbon Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9hum.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **library** instead of using a list. They are different. [Libraries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-libraries-b49f1617-c7c1-4078-b6b6-482500025d74) are used to store/manage files, but [lists](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-lists-0a1c3ace-def0-44af-b225-cfa8d92c52d7) are a collection of data which work like spreadsheets.

Learn more: [The difference between Lists and Libraries](https://veroniquepalmer.com/2013/02/24/the-difference-between-sharepoint-2010-lists-libraries-and-pages/)

Using a library, we can upload multiple files and folders.

[image]

Drag files and folders.

[image]

[How to create a library in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-document-library-in-sharepoint-306728fe-0325-4b28-b60d-f902e1d75939#ID0EAACAAA=2010)

Comment: hi yes we can use library but our client they wanted to save the document in list.So the requirement i have to implement this in list.

Comment: upload multiple documents the same ribbon i want to add it in sharepoint list